# EasyAdmin how to show image

Tags: image, easyadmin, symfony6

EasyAdmin 4, Symfony 6

I upload the image with setUploadDir, and would show im with setBasePath if I understand the doc, but image is not show on Index page.
When I juste cut and paste the image link in browser, symfony say: 'no route found for this link, can somebody help me please ?

```
    ImageField::new('officialLogo')
            ->onlyOnForms()
            ->setUploadDir('public/images/logos')
            ->setLabel('Logo Officiel (500 x 500):'),
   ImageField::new('officialLogo')->onlyOnIndex()->setBasePath('public/images/logo'),
```

Comment: base path should be ```->setBasePath('images/logo') ```